# PHPUnit doesn't work in Fedora 16

Tags: php, phpunit, fedora, symfony-1.4

Recently I upgrade my machine to fedora 16. PHPUnit worked fine on fedora 15. But after upgrade , when I run tests , it gives

**PHP Warning:  require_once(PHPUnit/Framework.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in "PATH TO MY TEST CLASSS".php on line 19
PHP Stack trace:**

```
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:44
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:125
PHP   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:145
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->loadSuiteClass() /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:104
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader->load() /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:168
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php:78
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:79
PHP   9. include_once() /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:95
```

**PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Framework.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in "PATH TO MY TEST CLASS".php on line 19
PHP Stack trace:**

```
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:44
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:125
PHP   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:145
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->loadSuiteClass() /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:104
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader->load() /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:168
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php:78
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:79
PHP   9. include_once() /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:95
```

What can be the issue for this. ? Any Help ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume you are installing PHPUnit through the fedora package manager? That would be the only reason why the os version would have any impact on that :)

In both cases your problem seems to be that you are running `PHPUnit 3.6.x` and your code base seems not be fit for this version and requires you to downgrade to `PHPUnit 3.5.15`

You can do this using the pear installer (instead of installing phpunit from packages) so remove the package and follow the relevant part of:

[**`Downgrading phpunit 3.6 to 3.5.15`**](http://dustyreagan.com/downgrade-phpunit-3-6-to-3-5-15/)

---

In general it is not needed to require that file anymore. The phpunit runner will that up everything and in case you are using some custom runner only `PHPUnit/Autoload.php` is needed.

The current way structuring phpunit test suites (recommended since 3.4.) is described here: [**`PHPUnit manual: Organizing tests`**](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/organizing-tests.html)

Comment: Hi edorian , Thank you very much for you answer.I downgrade the phpunit version to 3.5.15. Now it is working fine. Really appreciate your help .

Comment: He @wwyapa, glad i could help. If you problem is solved please click the little checkmark next to an answer once your question is solved. It lets everyone know that your problem is taken care of :)