# phpunit broke by Authorize.net

Tags: php, phpunit, authorize.net

I am running `phpunit .` in my project and get this:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(PHPUnit/Framework.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ****/anet_php_sdk/tests/AuthorizeNet_Test_Config.php on line 43
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Framework.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in ****/anet_php_sdk/tests/AuthorizeNet_Test_Config.php on line 43
```

I'm sure these libraries are fine. What is the easiest way to skip these tests or make them pass? I cannot downgrade phpunit like the discussion here [PHPUnit doesn't work in Fedora 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267838/phpunit-doesnt-work-in-fedora-16)

I am running PHPUnit 4.0.14

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `require_once(PHPUnit/Framework.php)` call in */anet_php_sdk/tests/AuthorizeNet_Test_Config.php* on line 43

PHPUnit 4.0.x will ship as PHAR package and include all files in one single file, so every require call to any external file will fail. PHPUnit comes with an autoloader and will load all the stuff by itself.